# UIRefreshControl overlapping headerview in uitableview

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uirefreshcontrol

I have a UITableView within my UIViewController and have added a UIRefreshControl as so:

```
lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ListViewController.handleRefresh), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

    return refreshControl
}()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.addSubview(self.refreshControl)
 }
```

It works fine but produces a nasty UI effect where it overlaps the header view.

[image]

I have tried setting the `frame height` and `contentInset` but neither worked.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `Adjust Scroll View Insets` ?

Comment: I tried your code and works fine. so show more images where you are facing issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I discovered was that I had to put a delay on the UIRefreshControl dismissal for the UI to function properly.

This may be very unique to me but I am posting it just in case.

```
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 0.5 // change to desired number of seconds
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
     refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```